# azure-eventhub jar upgrade required inside storm-eventhub jar

Tags: upgrade, apache-storm, azure-eventhub

I use storm-eventhub jar for my project using maven artifact as follows

`<groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
<artifactId>storm-eventhubs</artifactId>
<version>2.0.0</version>`

storm-eventhub internally uses azure-eventhub version 0.13.1 which is old one.
Hence we are forced to use the same version of azure-eventhub jar in our project as well.

Now the requirement is that we have to upgrade to azure-eventhub version 2.3.2 but storm-eventhub classes fail with NoClassDef errors since many classes refer to 0.13.1 version of azure-eventhub.

Should I customize the classes myself OR can I raise a request to apache community to upgrade the azure-eventhub version inside storm-eventhub library. If so, what would be the ETA approximately.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PR open to upgrade the client version for storm-eventhubs at https://github.com/apache/storm/pull/3004. Unfortunately it looks like the author didn't have time to finish it. You are welcome to pick it up.